# CSS same background-color as HTML5 Video? (Crossbrowser)

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, colors

How can I make a same color background with css and a video - so you can't see any tranisions? The issue is browser related and also related to the color-profile the monitor/system uses.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #0292c2;
}

video {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<video loop autoplay>
  <source src="https://dev.codebrauer.de/notgit/out.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="https://dev.codebrauer.de/notgit/out.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Safari**
[image: safari]

**Firefox** *Chrome is similiar*
[image: firefox]

**EDIT:**

Seems to be an only OS X Problem - on windows it's [looking good (Screenshots)](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/1a188829426c89806b8632d4aaf0b8cab7f2452d)

Comment: How are you collecting the background color?

Comment: All I see is the border bottom you have set on your firefox example. The Safari one, try just giving the containing element a transparent background.

Comment: Either you find out the exact color used in each browser and then useJS(if browser = etcetc), or you just make the background color transparent.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've created a video from png files with the same color `#0292c2`

Comment: @ChrisW. yes, i've set the border-bottom to better see where the video ends. the transparency didn't work.

Comment: @damianocelent this is what I want to avoid - also because this won't work if the user changes the color profile in his system.